# Scanner.equals() returns false in either case

Tags: java, if-statement

```
package harry;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class harry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String Harr = ("Harry");

        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);  

        System.out.println("Enter your name");  

        name.nextLine();

        if(name.equals("Harry")) {

            System.out.println("She hates you");    

        } else if (name.equals("Nick")) {

            System.out.println("She loves you");    
        }

    }

}
```

In this code, I am trying to write the following:

- If the name is “Harry”, it should print “She hates you”
- If the name is “Nick”, it should print “she loves you”

However, when I write either one of these names, it doesn’t print anything.

Answer (score 3):

Scanner is used a little differently :

```
package harry;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class harry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String Harr = ("Harry");

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   

        System.out.println("Enter your name");  

           String name = input.nextLine();

    if(name.equals("Harry")) {

            System.out.println("She hates you");    

        } else if (name.equals("Nick")) {

            System.out.println("She loves you");    
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Nick Nicholas it works when I try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class harry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String Harr = ("Harry");

        String s;

       Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);   

        System.out.println("Enter your name");  

           s = name.nextLine();

    if(s.equals("Harry")) {

            System.out.println("She hates you");    

        } else if (s.equals("Nick")) {

            System.out.println("She loves you");    
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of name.nextline to a string and then do the conditional check

The code will be like:

```
    String n= name.nextLine();

    if(n.equals("Harry")) {

        System.out.println("She hates you");    

    } else if (n.equals("Nick")) {

        System.out.println("She loves you");    
    }
```